# Livewire auto change content html to text wire:id

Tags: laravel-livewire

### Component A (Search)

component class:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Shared;

use Livewire\Component;

class Search extends Component
{
    public $searchString = '';

    public function updated()
    {
        $this->emitUp('searchForm', $this->searchString);
    }

    public function searchData()
    {
        $this->emitUp('searchForm', $this->searchString);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.shared.search');
    }
}
```

component view:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent='searchData' class="d-none d-sm-inline-block">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input wire:model.lazy='searchString' id="textSearch" name="textSearch" type="text"
            class="form-control bg-white border border-primary small" placeholder="Tìm kiếm...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

### Component B (List)

component class:

```
public $searchString = '';

protected $listeners = ['searchForm'];

public function searchForm($searchStringEmit)
    {
        $this->searchString = $searchStringEmit;
    }

public function getListSupplier()
    {
        $data = Supplier::where('active', true)
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->searchString . '%')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(2);

        return $data;
    }

public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.supplier.list', [
            'ListSupplier' => $this->getListSupplier()
        ]);
    }
```

---

I have problem with blade front-end. After I click button-search, component-search auto change component view show text wire:id<####>, instead of component-search view.
Example image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BLna.png)

Answer (score 0):

It should have been `<div wire:id="xxx">` that's how Livewire marks it's components. Make sure you don't have javascript doing some DOM manipulation. Check your template for more information

Comment: I sure you don't have javascript doing some DOM manipulation